# Checking for http references?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I recently set up my website to use https. I need to make sure that none of my pages reference http links (or else google gives a warning telling visitors that some assets are not secure). What is the most comprehensive way to test for the absence of these references (in both the head and body of each page) using capybara/rspec/selenium?

I've gotten as far as this to check for the head but don't know where to go from here or if this is the best way to do this:

```
    [15] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Template>)> page.all('head', visible: false).first
    => #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="head" path="/html/head">
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Did you mean that you want to make sure that none of your internal links are HTTP? If you're using URL helpers, this will just happen normally. If you're referencing a view inside your app using the absolute path, why are you doing that?

If you need to reference a view from an e-mail or a third party in general, it'd be better to set up an environment variable named HOST or something, that you can append paths to.

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(page).not_to have_link('', href: /http:/, visible: false)
```

should confirm there are no http links in your page.  If you're trying to check script tags, images, etc as well then it gets more complicated.  Along the lines of

```
expect(page).not_to have_selector('script[src^="http:"]', visible: false)
```

would be a start -- similar for images